# Is responsiveness a functional or non-functional requirement of system?

Tags: web-services, web, software-design

I understand that Responsiveness of a website is linked to **user-satisfaction**, so it is usually a non-functional requirement. But also it is **systems functionality** so it is functional requirement too.

I am confused because it may be consider either functional or non-functional...

Answer (score 3):

Functional requirements lists the operations or features that system must be able to do.

Non-functional requirements also known as qualitity attributes such as performance, security, usability is not a feature of the system.

To answer your question, **Responsiveness** is under the Performance requirements, therefore it is a non-functional requirement.

Don't think too much.

Answer (score 0):

> "... but also it is systems functionality... "

Consider a system in which a failure is defined as a certain functionality missing a deadline. In such cases one would be right to capture the time-sensitive nature of the function as a core system requirement i.e. **include the deadline within the requirements definition** and hence consider it a functional requirement.

In most cases though responsiveness is a non-functional requirement simply because there isn't any objective response-time requirement defined.

> **The audio-stream must play within 1ms of the video-stream** - is a functional requirement.
>
> **Faster/Smoother the animations, the better** - is a non-functional requirement.

Observe that the ***functional requirement* places a concrete restriction that can be later used to evaluated the implementation using a pass/fail criteria**. The *non-functional requirement* does not have any such implications on the system design/implementation.

---

In the context of preparing the  design document for a website, unless a specific deadline is clearly defined for a particular scenario, classify "**responsiveness**" as a non-functional requirement.